# Oracle query to find the top 2 item per group

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I want to right a sql query to find the top 2 item per group in oracle.
The table contains:

```
P_id Price GroupX
1     10    a 
2     5     a
3     5     a
4     4     b
5     8     b
6     6     b
```

Output should be:

```
P_id Price  GroupX
1     10      a
2     5       a
5     8       b
6     6       b
```

What I have tried is:

```
Select * from table
group by GroupX
order by price desc
limit 2
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using Oracle?  Your query does not look like an Oracle query.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
 Select  rnk,P_id, Price, GroupX 
        from (
             select P_id, Price, GroupX,
                  RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY GroupX
                           ORDER BY  Price DESC
               ) AS rnk
             from table
             )
        where rnk <= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function:

```
SELECT p_id,
       price,
       GroupX
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY groupX
                             ORDER BY Price DESC ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE rn <= 2;
```